# function receives value as undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a timeout which calls a function until 100% progress is complete. It then executes the function I have assigned to it. Only the value that was given to it is undefined or at least part of it.

I'm not sure at which stage the code is losing the value being passed, thus making it return `undefined` but I have made a JS Fiddle with it in action for you to see it:

[***JS Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ42h/2/)

My end result is to receive the value correct then remove the given element like so:

```
function rmv_div(div_id) {
   //div_id is not properly defined so cannot find the div.
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = div_id;
    var div = document.getElementById(div_id);
    div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `i` used inside `func` is created outside the scope of that function, and is increased at each iteration. Then, when you call `func` at the end, `i` equals `array.length`, so `array[i]` is undefined.

You can solve it creating another variable at each iteration that you won't increase:

**Solution 1**:

*Demo*: <del>http://jsfiddle.net/qJ42h/4/</del> http://jsfiddle.net/qJ42h/11/

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('bar' + array[i]),
        text = document.getElementById('text' + array[i]),
        remove = 'wrap' + array[i],
        j = i;
    do_something(bar, text, function () {
        rmv_div('id' + array[j]);
    }, 1);

}
```

**Solution 2**

*Demo*: <del>http://jsfiddle.net/qJ42h/8/</del> http://jsfiddle.net/qJ42h/12/

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('bar' + array[i]),
        text = document.getElementById('text' + array[i]),
        remove = 'wrap' + array[i];
    do_something(bar, text, (function(i) {
        return function(){ rmv_div('id' + array[i]); }
    })(i), 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why `j = i;` fixes it? I don't understand the difference

Comment: @Oriol - You have a semicolon that should be a comma in your var statement.

Comment: @dc5 i fixed it for him :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you didn't isolate the loop variable `i` inside the closure. However, this can be solved much more elegantly by using objects.

First off, I'm introducing the object that will encapsulate what you want; it gets initialized with a bar element and a function to call when it's done counting to 100. So, I'll call it `BarCounter`:

```
function BarCounter(element, fn)
{
    this.element = element;
    this.fn = fn;

    this.text = element.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    this.counter = 0;
}
```

This is just the constructor; it doesn't do anything useful; it resolves the text element, which is simply the first `<div>` tag it can find underneath the given element and stores that reference for later use.

Now we need a function that will do the work; let's call it `run()`:

```
BarCounter.prototype.run = function()
{
    var that = this;

    if (this.counter < 100) {
        this.text.innerHTML = this.counter++;

        setTimeout(function() {
            that.run();
        }, 70);
    } else {
        this.fn(this.element);
    }
}
```

The function will check whether the counter has reached 100 yet; until then it will update the text element with the current value, increase the counter and then call itself again after 70 msec. You can see how the reference to `this` is kept beforehand to retain the context in which the `run()` function is called later.

When all is done, it calls the completion function, passing in the element on which the `BarCounter` object operates.

The completion function is much easier if you pass the element to remove:

```
function removeDiv(element)
{
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

The final step is to adjust the rest of your code:

```
var array = [1];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var bar = new BarCounter(
        document.getElementById('bar' + array[i]), 
        removeDiv
    );
    bar.run();
}
```

It's very simple now; it creates a new `BarCounter` object and invokes its `run()` method. Done :)

Btw, you have the option to remove the element from within the object as well; this, of course, depends on your own needs.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ42h/13/)